# User ability to favorite or 'like' content

Tags: users

I have a few different custom content types and would like to give my users the ability to favorite or 'like' (like Facebook, but not for Facebook) pieces of content so that they can later view a list of their favorited content.

I've searched everywhere but haven't come up with a clean solution. I'm pretty comfortable with SQL and PHP but want to make sure I'm doing this in the most efficient, clean way possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have already thought of this, but have you thought about a plugin.

I was sure that the WPMU Dev guys did one that did a like (that wasn't FB related) but I can't find it (if you want to look it must be somewhere here but I've gone through it all and I can't find it now http://premium.wpmudev.org/wordpress-plugins/)

I also found these plugins which might help:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/i-like-this/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-like/

(Unfortunately I've not had time to test them first, which I usually like to do before recommending stuff, but maybe they'll help you in any case)

Cheers

Nick

Comment: I actually ended up hacking the hell out of a plugin called 'NS Like It' but I'll give you the checkmark anyways :)